# Does a form attribute have to be input when calling form.serializable()

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I am to POST to either a PHP file or an JSP file and I use **form.serialize()** in an **ajax** call, does the elements of the form need to be **input** tags? Or can it be for example a **label** and still be used in the php/jsp file if it has a name and id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `serialize` method will get the data from all the (successful) form controls. That includes inputs and selects.

A label isn't a form control, doesn't have a name (it is invalid to give it a name attribute), and doesn't have a value, so it wouldn't be included.

Labels are there to tell users what sort of thing to enter into a form control. They aren't a means for the user to provide data in their own right.